# Key error in python pandas while trying to compare values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the exponential moving average (EMA of 100 periods) so for that, I have the following code. It works fine but in my pandas, I will be comparing this value with the closing value of a candlestick (getting 200-period OHLCV data from binance) The condition I am specifying is if ema - close <0 then its worth is true else false Till here the code works fine. The problem is when there is a change in condition all the previous values also change (example: if the second last value is false, and the current value is true, all become true and vice versa) what I am trying to achieve is the previous value should remain same and the focus should be on the current value Also I am getting `KeyError: 'worth'`I think it has something to do with the range I am mentioning in for loop  the value `len(df.index) is 200`
Please don't get confused with the name `last_fifty_rows` I have been experimenting with different periods hence the name. Any insight here is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: I have mentioned in comments that removing [current] it calculates the values but the True/False value is incorrect. I have attached the screenshot of output for reference[image]

```
last_row_index = len(df.index) - 1
    previous_row_index = last_row_index - 1
    last_fifty_rows = len(df.index) - 100
    ema8 = ta.trend.ema_indicator(df['close'], 100)
        df['ema'] = ema8
        for current in range(last_fifty_rows, len(df.index)):
            previous = current - 1
            if (df['ema'][last_fifty_rows] - df['close'][last_fifty_rows]) < 0:
             df['worth'][current]= 'True' #......if changed to df['worth'] it works
            elif (df['ema'][last_fifty_rows] - df['close'][last_fifty_rows]) > 0:
             df['worth'][current]= 'False' #.....if changed to df['worth'] it works
            else:
                df['worth'][current]=df['worth'][previous]
    
        print(df.tail(5))
```

Comment: `df['worth']` must be an existing column before assigning value.

Comment: @im0j thanks for the reply. I am confused here, if I just use df['worth']=true it works but the calculation is messed up

Comment: Assigning a scalar value (in this case, `'True'`) initializes the whole column with it, which is not what you want.

Comment: @im0j How do you suggest I approach this problem. Do I have to add the column 'worth' and then use df['worth'][current]= 'True'? I am just learning and experimenting with python. Apologies if this is a silly question..

Comment: @im0j Thanks so much man I just got it I initialized the value for df['worth'] before the loop and it solved the problem. Have a great day!!!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for this, I solved the whole issue and got my desired output by just adding the line: `df['worth']=False` before the loop starts.

So now my code is as follows:

```
    last_row_index = len(df.index) - 1
    previous_row_index = last_row_index - 1
    last_fifty_rows = len(df.index) - 100
    df['worth']=False
    ema8 = ta.trend.ema_indicator(df['close'], 100)
        df['ema'] = ema8
        for current in range(last_fifty_rows, len(df.index)):
            previous = current - 1
            if (df['ema'][last_fifty_rows] - df['close'][last_fifty_rows]) < 0:
             df['worth'][current]= 'True' #......if changed to df['worth'] it works
            elif (df['ema'][last_fifty_rows] - df['close'][last_fifty_rows]) > 0:
             df['worth'][current]= 'False' #.....if changed to df['worth'] it works
            else:
                df['worth'][current]=df['worth'][previous]
    
        print(df.tail(5))
```